# Spring Data JPA repository query builder, many to many relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to construct a `find` query in my repository interface to select all elements mapped by many to many relationship.

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "passwordHash")
    private String passwordHash;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersTracking")
    private Set<Show> shows;
...
```

Show.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shows")
public class Show {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "imdb_id", length = 9, nullable = false)
    private String imdbID;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "poster_url", length = 255, nullable = true)
    private String posterURL;

    @Column(name = "rating", length = 3, nullable = true)
    private double rating;

    @Column(name = "genre", length = 100, nullable = true)
    private String genre;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_shows",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "show_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<User> usersTracking;
...
```

To achieve that using query builder (I think it's called) I have written a repository:

```
public interface ShowRepository extends CrudRepository<Show, UUID> {
    List<Show> findByUser(User user);
}
```

But I would like to be able to get shows from my UserRepository rather than ShowRepository, so I should write something like this?

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> {
    List<Show> findShows();
    //Or maybe?
    List<Show> findShowsByUser(User user);
}
```

Am I even understanding this whole query building correctly?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  `List<Show> findShowsByUser(User user)` on `UserRepository` is not required.  If you already have a `User`, you can just call `user.getShows()` to get the shows for that user.  Not sure about the first query method because it does not have any parameters.

Comment: @manish This may be very stupid but I've struggled with this for a few minutes before reading your comment and calling the getter. Thanks.